# PHP/mysql memory error Drupal

Tags: php, mysql, drupal

So I am working in a local drupal CMS environment and am easily able to navigate through and open any pages to view or edit. But the moment I try to save changes or delete pages I get one of the two following errors.

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 76 bytes) in /Users/krice/projects/drupal/includes/database.mysql.inc on line 145

Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded in /Users/krice/projects/drupal/includes/database.mysql.inc on line 109

Here is my my.cnf file and my php.ini file I have (the parts that matter if i need to show more i can)

my.cnf

```
# The MySQL server
[mysqld]
port        = 8889
socket      = /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock
skip-external-locking
key_buffer_size = 384M
max_allowed_packet = 16M
table_open_cache = 512
sort_buffer_size = 2M
read_buffer_size = 2M
read_rnd_buffer_size = 8M
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 64M
thread_cache_size = 8
query_cache_size= 32M
# Try number of CPU's*2 for thread_concurrency
thread_concurrency = 8
tmp_table_size=2G
max_heap_table_size=2G
```

php.ini

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Resource Limits ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

max_execution_time = 60     ; Maximum execution time of each script, in seconds
max_input_time = 60 ; Maximum amount of time each script may spend parsing request data
memory_limit = 2048M      ; Maximum amount of memory a script may consume (8MB)
```

As you can see I have tried uping my max execution time and memory_limit and still does the same thing but now it waits 60 seconds then gives me the errors.

Any help would be greatly appreciated and if you need more info I can provide it thanks.

Comment: Show Your phpinfo values of memory_limit. You should boost Your php ressources. Time to 5 minutes. Memory to 256M.

Comment: did you actually reboot apache after changing the php.ini? :)

Comment: @Fedir The memory_limit is already at 512MB (says so in the error message) and a maximum execution time of 60sec (says so in the error message) should be enough.

Comment: what queries are executing when the error occurs ?

Comment: @fedir the memory limit is at 2048M (2G) its in the php.ini snippet above.

julien Yes good thought

Stephan a simple change to a page using the CMS and then saving the changes

Comment: it could be host side problem ..change it

Comment: @Deonia Well other devs here are not having the same problem and it works fine in production its only on my local machine that the problem occures (running 8GB Ram on a MacBook Pro 2009, 10.8.3) We can't figure out why mine is the only one having the problem

Comment: Put maximal ressources, memory to 1GB. And when it will work make a php profiling to find the part which takes all the ressources.

Comment: Set 400MB for memory limit and you should be able to save anything!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to find out which module causes the excessive memory and time consumption.

1. Find out in which function the memory_limit is exhaused (i.e. to what function does line 145 of *database.mysql.inc* belong to).
2. Modify that function such that it logs the [`debug_backtrace()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php) whenever it is called.
3. Find out which module initiated the last call.

Comment: Thanks Oswald we ended up setting up a vigrant/virtual machine enviornment and it ended up solving the problem. Thanks for the help though!